# ubuntu custom nuget feed with NTLM auth

Tags: .net, ubuntu, nuget

good day everyone
we have private nuget feed with internal libraries which use NTLM authorization
also i have ubuntu (18.04) server with .net core sdk 3.1.101 
when i try to build my project via:

`dotnet publish foo.csproj --configuration Development --output bin/publish`

then i receive errors:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://nuget.local/nuget/FindPackagesById()?id='<redacted>'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm "domain").
```

i specify nuget username/password for my feed in NuGet.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="local" value="http://nuget.local/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <local>
        <add key="Username" value="user@domain" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="redacted" />
      </local>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

but i can execute curl without any problems:

`curl --ntlm --user user@domain:redacted http://nuget.local/nuget`

where is not any kerberos configuration on ubuntu machine was done

**UPDATE 22.05**

i try to configure kerberos on ubuntu machine. after configure dns, hostname and kerberos config i try to receive kerberos ticket:

`kinit user@domain`
and didn't receive any errors, also i can view received ticket by execute `klist`

now, then i try to execute `dotnet restore` i receive another error:

`KDC reply did not match expectations`

there is my krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true

[realms]
        DOMAIN = {
                kdc = ad
                admin_server = ad
        }

[domain_realm]
        .domain = DOMAIN
        domain = DOMAIN
```

a also have search and default domain in resolv.conf:

```
domain domain
search domain
nameserver 192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding basic validAuthenticationTypes, and use a PAT for the password instead of the plain-text password:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3"/>
    <add key="local" value="http://nuget.local/nuget" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <local>
        <add key="Username" value="user@domain" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="redacted" />
        <add key="ValidAuthenticationTypes" value="basic" /> 
      </local>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```